# Simple 5 Digit Timer Not Displaying Expected Result

Tags: javascript

The code below is supposed to result in a five-digit timer (EX: 2:32:18) that counts up by seconds. The variables "one" to "five" represent place values, where "five" represents hours and "one" represents the first digit of seconds. I would really appreciate some explanation on why this isn't displaying properly...

```
<html>
    <body>
    
        <p id="clock"></p>
    
        <script>
        
            let one = 0;
            let two = 0;
            let three = 0;
            let four = 0;
            let five = 0;
            
            function counter() {            
                
                if (one = 10) {
                    two ++;
                    one = 0;
                }
        
                if (two = 6) {
                    three ++;
                    two = 0;
                }
    
                if (three = 10) {
                    four ++;
                    three = 0;
                }
        
                if (four = 6) {
                    five ++;
                    four = 0;
                }
        
                one++;
                
                var oneS = one.toString();
                var twoS = two.toString();
                var threeS = three.toString();
                var fourS = four.toString();
                var fiveS = five.toString();

                document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = fiveS + ":" + fourS + threeS + ":" + twoS + oneS;
                
                setTimout(counter, 1000);
            }
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A few issues found:

1. The `counter` function never gets invoked because the `setTimeout` statement was placed inside of the `counter` function. Move it out of the curly brackets.
2. Typo, should be `setTimeout` instead of `setTimout`
3. Use `setInterval` instead since I assume you want to invoke the function repeatedly